# For a ring $R$, if $ab=ca$ implies $b=c$, show $R$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If R be a ring and assume that for all a,b,c belongs to R ab=ca implies b=c, then prove that R is a commutative ring

Comment: Next time, put the tags in the tags section and not in the title, and use a title that is *actually useful.*

Answer (score 3):

For any $a,b$ in the ring, $aba=a \times ba = ab \times a$ so by the defining property $ab=ba$.